# My function only works if there is a printf before it

Tags: c, function

I'm doing a class homework, I wrote a function to erase a element from an array, and it started failing when trying to erase the next to last element.  It sometime would erase the last 2 elements.

The code is half done, BTW.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <windows.h>

enum
{
    MAX = 10
};

struct lista
{
    int array[MAX];
    int NELMS;
};

struct numero
{
    int numero;
    struct lista posiciones;
    int repe;
};

void scanlist(struct lista* list)
{
    printf("Introduzca 10 números: ");
    list->NELMS = 10;
    for(int i = 0; i < list->NELMS; i++){
        scanf(" %d", &list->array[i]);
    }
}

void printlist(const struct lista* L)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < L->NELMS; i++){
        printf("%d ",L->array[i]);
    }
}

void borrar(struct lista* list, int posicion)    // This is the function that works weird
{
    for(int i = posicion; i < list->NELMS; i++){
        list->array[i] = list->array[i+1];

    }
    list->NELMS --;
   // printf(" ");                               // Depending if this is commented or not, it 
                                                 // works or not (works when uncommented)
}


void singulares (const struct lista* L1, struct lista* L2)
{
    *L2 = *L1;

    for(int i = 0; i < L2->NELMS; i++){
        for(int k = i+1; k < L2->NELMS; k++){
            if(L2->array[i] == L2->array[k])
            {
                borrar(L2, k);
                L2->NELMS--;
            }
        printlist(L2);
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
}


/*buscador(struct lista* list, struct numero numero)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list->NELMS, i++){

    }
}*/


int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
    SetConsoleCP(1252);

    struct lista list1;
  //  struct lista list2;

    scanlist(&list1);

   // singulares(&list1,&list2);

    borrar(&list1, 8);

    printlist(&list1);
    printf("\n%d",list1.NELMS);
                                     // 7 10 143 10 52 143 72 10 143 7 (Numbers to try)
}
```

I tried to erase the next to last element from the array and it only worked if there was some printf before.

Comment: Watch the value of `NELEMS` when you call `borrar` and then follow up by `L2->NELMS--`. Also watch out for accessing past the end of the array.

Comment: Errors that only occur when you add or remove an irrelevant statement are a strong indication of undefined behavior in the program. Look for buffer overflows and invalid pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading off the end of your buffer. The behavior is undefined. Here is the offending code:

```
for(int i = posicion; i < list->NELMS; i++){
    list->array[i] = list->array[i+1];
}
```

When `list->NELMS` is 10, then `list->array[i+1]` will access past the end of that array on the last iteration.

Since there is no point in moving values that are past the end, just don't do it. You can instead decrement the list size *first*, and then move the value with the same loop:

```
void borrar(struct lista* list, int posicion)
{
    if (posicion >= 0 && posicion < list->NELMS)
    {
        list->NELMS--;
        for(int i = posicion; i < list->NELMS; i++){
            list->array[i] = list->array[i+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the elements do not get "erased". The unused elements of your array will still contain whatever value was most recently stored there.